# Bearer before token in JWT

Tags: security, token, jwt, access-token

I have noticed the convention is to send a JWT in the header under the field Authorization. The standard is to send the token as such:

```
Authorization:Bearer [token]
```

My question is why do I need to put the Bearer part why not just:

```
Authorization:[token]
```

When I receive the first request I need to parse every request to get rid of the Bearer when I verify my JWT. What is the point of this?

Comment: It was started by HTTP itself, that standardised `Authorization: Basic` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#section-2, then promoted further by oauth that introduced `Authorization: Bearer` (and others) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-7.1 So it is there to specify what type of authentication credentials is being sent.

Comment: @zerkms Is it mandatory though? If I avoid it will there be any consequences? My server simply receives the token and verifies if it is a valid token I issued.

Comment: It is not mandatory. RFC 2616 defines it as `Authorization  = "Authorization" ":" credentials` so it's up to you on how you construct the credentials part https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.8

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was started in the HTTP 1.0 standard, that added the [`Authorization: Basic`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2).

Then some other popular protocols (/frameworks) popularised other kinds of authentication, like [OAuth's `Authorization: Bearer`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7.1).

Practically, the HTTP standard (both ["obsolete"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8) and ["more modern"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)) declare it as

```
Authorization = "Authorization" ":" credentials
```

without any constraints on how the `credentials` to be shaped.

So it is up to you on what you put there, as soon as it works for you.